# Making a count-up with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, count, countdown

I'm trying to make a count up animation in Javascript. That is to say, the animation would start at 0, then, given an animation duration, count up to a given number. Is this possible in Javascript?
Additionally, is it possible to have the animation play only once the user scrolls down to that point on the page?

Comment: You're *trying*. That is to say you've done some work. May we see it?

Comment: So far, I haven't actually got anything.

Comment: What are you 'animating'? Images of the numbers, the numbers themselves (as text)? Something else?

Comment: They're numbers, as in actual type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(function (e) {
    setTimeout(function () {
         e += 1;
    }, 1000).call(this, 0);
```

It counts, after all?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried taking a look at the `setInterval(func, delay[, param1, param2, ...])` method?

From Mozilla Developer Network:

> Calls a function or executes a code snippet repeatedly, with a fixed time delay between each call to that function.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=window.setInterval

To illustrate how to use the `setInterval` method to create a simple counter that starts counting at 0 and increments every second, I have created this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zrccC/ - the sample also illustrates how to clear the timer.

Comment: I think you should give him an MDN link instead of a W3Schools link.